# Write quotation mark in aspx merged code

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why this code doesn't work?

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("return confirm('¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el registro {0}?);'", Eval("data")) %>'
```

The error is:

> The server tag is not well formed.

How can I write this to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The second ' is telling the string to end. Escape it using a backslash. Same with the ending apostrophe.

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("return confirm(\'¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el registro {0}?);\'", Eval("data")) %>'
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Use @ at the start of the string so that escape characters are not processed. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(VS.71).aspx

```
OnClientClick='<%# Eval("data", @"return confirm('¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el registro {0}?);'") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It also appears that the string within the confirm function is not closed prior to the closing paren. Should be:

```
confirm('¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el registro {0}?');
```